# Linking scenes with lights

Tags: light, linked-data

I'm rendering simple objects with Blender in batches, and I'd like to be able to render them easily with different kind of ambiances & cameras.

So far, I have the following :

- Different "Camera scenes", each with various cameras & camera animations. They contain ONLY this. (Let's say I have 3 different scenes C1, C2 and C3, each with various camera setups)
- Different "Light scenes", containing what I will call light parameters : A world (HDR & co) and some lights. (Same, let's call them L1, L2, L3)
- And finally, scenes that I use for my renderings. These are empty scenes, but they each link to a Camera scene and a Light scene (one of each). Let's call the combination of "camera scene C1" & "light scene L1" C1L1.

My goal is to have an optimal number of rendering types, with minimal maintenance : So I can have scenes C1L1, C1L2, C2L1, C3L3,  ... and only update the subscenes C1, C2, L1, [...] when I'm not happy with a specific part of a rendering. The fact that I'm linking to a scene directly and not to each specific light & camera allows me to not only edit the light settings, but also to rename, add, and remove anything without further modification.

For now, I'm able to do exactly this for world shader & cameras : In my linking scene, I just need to select the proper world data-block that was imported with the linked scene (otherwise I get no ambient lighting), and if the camera is properly selected in the linked camera-scene, every thing works smoothly.
However, I can't have lights to work properly in my final render; The lights seems to be disabled, and I don't get any lighting or shadows from them. I figured this was because the lights were in a subscene, and thus, not activated.

An option for me to solve this would be to update my scripts to append everything from C1, L1 ..., instead of linking against them, but just for knowledge, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this through the linking mecanism.

Thanks !

Edit : How to reproduce ?

**Desired result :** 
Just open Blender, with the default scene, and switch to rendered shading in the 3D viewer. The cube should be lit.

**Current result :**

- Open Blender's default scene. Remove the camera and the cube. Save it as "Light.blend". It should only contain world & Lamp.
- Open Blender's default scene again. Remove the cube, world, and Lamp. Save it as "Camera.blend". It should only contain Camera.
- Open Blender's default scene. Remove everything but the cube : world, lamp and camera. Go to file > Link > and choose Light.blend > scenes > scene. Do the same with Camera.blend > scenes > scene.
- Switch to rendered shading. The cube should appear black, instead of being properly lit. 
  [image: Current result][image: Expected result]